# prevent redirects if not on same domain (javascript)

Tags: javascript, redirect

Is there a way to prevent redirects if they aren't on the same domain? There's this snippet that works well:

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return true;
  }
```

But the problem is that it prompts user on every redirect. I would like to truncate prompts only to different domain redirects. I've tried:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
  if (!location.href.match('domain')) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return true;
    }
  }
```

and

```
    window.onhashchange = function() {
  if(!location.href.match('domain')) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return true;
    };
  }
}
```

and plenty of other variations but they don't seem to work. Did anyone have a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)'s property `hostname`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return window.location.hostname !== 'example.com'; // your domain
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: using JS it isn't possible to know what the next adress is so it can't be done due to privacy policy.